# Scheduled task executor crashed unexpectedly

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an application under Spring boot 1.3.x and Feign client for REST calls.

Every 2 minutes, I launch a Scheduled task to retrieve datas from another service. This service starts to send SocketTimeoutException and Feign Client launched 3 retries. All retries throws a SocketTimeoutException.

After this sequence, no scheduled task have been executed. There is no other exception, no information about the ThreadPool is down. Nothing...

Do you have any idea what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please enable debug log to see more details on the exceptions.

Comment: It happens only once in production environment. I have no more log than those SocketTimeoutException launched 3 times and after that no other schedule tasks has been executed.